# How do you change the list so that it becomes a label?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

[I want to change the list in the image title to a label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3E7C.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.xlabel("Some label")
plt.ylabel("other label")
```